# Django query exclude runtime

Tags: sql, django

I'm wondering about SQL query performance. Let's say I'm doing the following query:

`MyModel.objects.exclude(indexed_field=list_of_field_values)`

`list_of_field_values` isn't a queryset -- it's an actual list. How will the performance change as `list_of_field_values` grows? What happens when it goes from 1000 to 2000 elements, for example?